# Calculating lateral/longitudinal acceleration/jerk

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, jerk

I know how to calculate the lateral and longitudinal velocities given the velocity $v$ and heading angle $\theta$ :

$ v_{lat} = v × \ \mathrm{sin} \theta$

$v_{long} = v× \cos \theta$

But does this extend to acceleration $a$ and jerk $j$, i.e.,

$a_{lat} = a × \sin \theta$

$a_{long} = a × \cos \theta$

$j_{lat} = j × \sin \theta$

$j_{long} = j \cos \theta$

?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, I am asking - are these equations equivalent:

1. a_lat = a*sin(theta) & a_lat = derivative(v_lat)

2. a_long = a*cos(theta) & a_long = derivative(v_long)

3. j_lat = j*sin(theta) & j_lat = derivative(a_lat)

4. j_long = j*cos(theta) & j_long = derivative(a_long)

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since the acceleration and jerk are both vector quantities, your equations should be ok.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe that too, but is there any literature I could read on this?